# OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't draw anything

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es, 3d

I have a problem with OpenGl ES 2.0. I've designed a very simple framework to help me load OBJ files and draw them on my Android phone, but I have 2 bugs that I haven't been able to fix:

1. My app doesn't show anything until I change the orientation and the Activity gets scraped and reloaded. Until it reloads only GLES20.glClear() can be seen(I've set it to a grayish color).
2. Sometimes when I load an OBJ and do the orientation trick, half of my faces are missing and I see gaps, but the problem might be with the OBJ files I've used.

```
package com.ideas.opengl;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class DemoRenderer implements Renderer {
    public static int mProgramHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    public Object banana;

    private OpenGLDemoActivity activity;

    private int angle;

    public DemoRenderer(OpenGLDemoActivity activity) throws IOException {
        this.activity = activity;
    }



    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f);

        //GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        Shader shader = null;
        try {
            shader = new Shader(activity, "simple");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Vector position = new Vector();
        Vector speed = new Vector();
        Vector accel = new Vector();
        Model model = null;
        try {
            model = new Model("banana", activity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        banana = new Object(position, speed, accel, model);

        mProgramHandle = shader.getProgramHandle();

        final float eyeX = 0.0f;
        final float eyeY = 0.0f;
        final float eyeZ = 3.5f;

        final float lookX = 0.0f;
        final float lookY = 0.0f;
        final float lookZ = -5.0f;

        final float upX = 0.0f;
        final float upY = 1.0f;
        final float upZ = 0.0f;

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0f;
        final float top = 1.0f;
        final float near = 1.0f;
        final float far = 10.0f;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {      
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        angle++;

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        banana.draw();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: No one even interested in helping...?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong there. Are you using glGetError in your code anywhere? You should read how it works and use it to check for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've found error 1281 to be the culprit. I'm trying now to debug.

Comment: This appears to be the GL_INVALID_VALUE...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The important thing to do is to find which command is generating it. You'll have to add/move around glGetError calls until you find the line that generates the error. The man page for that command will tell you what kind of errors it generates and why.

Comment: I've done that, found the code:

Comment: mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(DemoRenderer.mProgramHandle, "a_Position");
  mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(DemoRenderer.mProgramHandle, "a_Normal");
  
  mTextCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(DemoRenderer.mProgramHandle, "a_TextCoord");

Comment: I've found the problem: mProgramHandle was being use before it had its value changed. Thanks a bunch! You deserve a beer, sir!

Comment: BTW, please post and answer so that I can call it answered.

Comment: Hm... I keep getting another GL_INVALID_VALUE while trying to bind my buffer, although everything appears to work ok...

Comment: This is the code: GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);

  GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
  GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer.capacity() * mBytesPerFloat, verticesBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);   


  mBufferIndex = buffers[0]; GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferIndex);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried some glGetError() and got to errors, one regarding a variable that had its value unchanged and another was that glGetAttributeLocation() return a -1 if the attribute is not used in the vertex shader. Thaks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the geometry is likely due to using the same float array for input and output in the matrix multiplication:
`Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);`
According to the multiplyMM() specs the input and output arrays may not have overlapping elements, but you use the same array mMVPMatrix starting with the same index 0. One way to fix the problem is to use another matrix as a buffer for the result of the last multiplication, so instead of:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

use:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrixFinal, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMatrixFinal, 0);
```